# What are the existing results on the $C^{0}$ estimate of the solution of the semi-linear pde $\Delta u = f(x,u,\nabla u)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I have read several papers but their conditions are so strong which always assume that $f(x,z,\eta)$ is controlled by $\left| \eta \right|$, for example:
$\left| f\right| \leq C(\left| \eta \right|^{2}+g(x))$

What I want to ask is that if there are any better results about the $C^{0}$ estimate I still don't know.

Comment: A $C^0$ estimate is really the same as an $L^\infty$ estimate, which you should be able to get with a maximum principle. Quadratic growth in $\nabla u$ should typically not be required, since the maximum principle argument would be applied at points in the domain where $\nabla u = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, at the maximum or minimum point $\Delta u \leq or \geq 0$, $\nabla u=0$, then we can get some boundness, but I wonder if there are some new methods.